# Export OSB resources without using export wizard on JDeveloper

Tags: oracle12c, jdeveloper, osb, oracle-service-bus

Using JDeveloper in order to create and manage Oracle Service Bus 12c resources, I am able to export the required resources into a .jar file using the Resources Export Wizard of JDeveloper, selecting one by one those needed, under the tree of each project.

What I want to do though is find a way to export a .jar file based on resources list, given in a file of a commonly used format (JSON, CSV etc), as it can be time saving for a large number of resources. My first thought was to search if JDeveloper provides such way or attempt do this programmatically, yet my search on this has not given me any information of how-to.

Is there an alternative way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Oracle OSB 11.1.1.7.0 or higher you can automate the compilation process for OSB at project level using **configjar**, here's a whole [example of an implementation](http://migueleonardortiz.com.ar/python/oracle-service-bus-osb-automated-compilation-with-configjar/1375) which include: compilation using configjar, automating the task retrieving the code from GIT using Jenkins and a python script.

You can also do it using ANT, here's a [good document of Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/dev.1111/e15866/tasks.htm#OSBDV128) explaining that. (I've tried it, but found easier to use configjar, this is the only option for versions below 11.1.1.7.0).

After creating any of those compilation methods you can create a CSV file, [parse it with python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and loop the compilation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very helpful.

Comment: @NickL. glad to help!